# I couldn't install @angular/cli on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I tried many times to install @angular/cli on Ubuntu terminal but I got an error like this

```
**npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @angular/cli@latest**.
```

I installed nodejs with nvm and NVM_BIN path **/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.6.1/bin/node**. I saw many examples. That said node path must be **/usr/local/node**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it . The main problem was related with terminal that permissions. I had installed NodeJS with root privilege before I was installing angular cli with the root and I tried many times to install angular cli but I got some errors. Finally I did it without root instead of that I used default current user privilege. Thank you all that who help me to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with any system path resolution, you are facing this problem because `npm` is not able to resolve the given package. 
You can try following solutions for this problem

1. run `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` and then run `npm install -g @angular/angular-cli`
2. If You still facing problem, try changing internet/network you are connected on, some of user have posted the issue on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6669) that when they are using their employers or using any kind of VPN they are unable to install but changing to network solved their issue